# Why is there no "scroll down/up" functionality with Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, selenium-chromedriver, capybara

Every implementation of scrolling I have seen requires executing Javascript (`scrollTop`, `scrollTo` for example), rather than an available method in Selenium Webdriver to perform this action. Since Webdriver is designed to perform the same interactions in a browser that a user might take, why is this not found anywhere?

I understand that using Webdriver to interact with an element in the DOM saves from having to scroll elements, however some libraries like ReactVirtualized are designed to only render *visible* rows, making automation that much more difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using Capybara (as your question is tagged) or selenium-webdriver directly?

If using Capybara then you want the `scroll_to` method - https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/capybara/Capybara/Node/Element#scroll_to-instance_method - which was recently added.

If you're using `selenium-webdriver` directly, it's because for a long time there was insistence by some of the writers of the WebDriver spec that scrolling wasn't necessary. That insistence changed at the last WebDriver spec meeting but details of how scrolling should work haven't actually been added to the spec yet.

Comment: I am using an older Capyabara gem. Thank you for the heads up as any Google searches bring up results from way back in 2014! Slightly OT: Are there resources out there that could help me stay better informed of these updates & key points of discussion?

Comment: @Phil For Capybara you can follow the github repo and read the changes - https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/blob/master/History.md - `scroll_to` was added in 3.13.  For the webdriver spec you can read the meetings minutes - https://www.w3.org/2018/10/26-webdriver-minutes.html#item02